# Proper way to handle a lock file on rebase conflict

Tags: pnpm, lockfile, pnpm-workspace

Hi I am not sure if I am doing things correctly. Whenever I rebase an hit an issue with `package.json` and the lock file. I fix the package.json, but then delete the lockfile and just run `pnpm i` again.

But recently I noticed an issue where the lockfile in the master branch and a newly generated lockfile were different.

My team members were like, you should never try to generate a new lockfile. Just keep running `pnpm i`.

So am I doing this wrong, or do you think we actually have botched locking file in our master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are conflicts, you may run `pnpm install`. pnpm will automatically resolve the conflicts and create a new lockfile that you may commit.

IMO, removing the lockfile and running `pnpm install` is also fine. However, some teams prefer to update dependencies as rarely as possible. If you remove the lockfile, newer versions of dependencies might be installed.

You may also try the [resolution-mode=time-based](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#resolution-mode) setting. With this setting dependencies will be rarely updated. Even if you remove the lockfile.